# Hibernate changes database change from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am using `Spring` and `Hibernate` in my project. My database has changed from `Oracle` 10g to `MySQL`.

Can you please tell me what changes do I need to make in my `Hibernate` configuration?

Also are there any changes required in my `Java` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hibernate.cfg.xml for your project to define the database property, then you need to change it to the below values for MySQL :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{db.name}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">{db.name}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">{db.password}</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Also you need to include the mysql-connector jar in your pom.xml for example

```
  <!--Mysql-Connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
```

if you are not using the hibernate.cfg.xml and instead using some `sessionFactory` bean in your Spring `ApplicationContext.xml`. Then you need to change it to below :-

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">

        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- As of now not using hibernate.cfg.xml -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
   </bean>
```

Please follow http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring for complete example on how to setup hibernate with spring.

Comment: let me know if you face any issue ?

Comment: you are using apache tomcat server but I am using jetty server. so i think <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">       will be change..?

Comment: @BiswajitMondal yup it needs to be changed according to the application server. you can search the exact class name on the internet.. but to answer your actual question, you need to change the DBDialect and include the db-connector jar, other property will vary based on your setup. its just an example i copy paste as you didn't include that detail in your question.